# Создание структур C++

Tags: c++, c++11

Не очень понимаю, что я делаю не так. Программа просто завершается (с кодом 0) и ничего не выводит.

```
struct Date {
    int day;
    int month;
    int year;

    char *toString() {
        char *out = nullptr;
        sprintf(out, "%d-%d-%d", day, month, year);
        return out;
    }

    Date(int day, int month, int year) {
        this->day = day;
        this->month = month;
        this->year = year;
    }
};

int main() {
        Date *date = new Date(25, 11, 17);
        printf("%s", (*date).toString());
}
```

Comment: Так `char *out = nullptr;`  писать нельзя. Дата выводится "вникуда" и как итог - пусто в  `return out`.

Comment: Замени char *out = nullptr; на char *out = new char[50];

Comment: Вот эта задача показывает, что в "перспективе" `char *out = new char[50]` приведёт к утечке памяти, что бы её не было, нужно ссылки коллекционировать - потом освобождать, позже это стало GC называться. Ещё как вариант "для отладки" или для single-thread можно подставлять "статический буфер". Но в даном случае new можно использовать.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ну кто же пишет по **нулевому** адресу?

```
    char *out = nullptr;
    sprintf(out, "%d-%d-%d", day, month, year);
```

Сделайте, например, так:

```
struct Date {
    int day;
    int month;
    int year;
    char buf[20];

    char *toString()
    {
        sprintf(buf, "%d-%d-%d", day, month, year);
        return buf;
    }
```

и в конструкторе еще сразу же вызов `toString()` или `buf[0]=0;`.

Comment: nullptr это же не обязательно нулевой адрес?

Comment: Это в любом случае несуществующий адрес - в смысле, который не может принадлежать ни одному объекту...

Comment: T.е. термин "нулевой адрес"  здесь подразумевает не адрес ячейки под номером ноль, а нулевой указатель?

Comment: А ещё Герб Саттер советует запомнить одно простое правило: "никогда не используйте sprintf".

Comment: @retorta В данном случае проблема не в этом :) Кстати, любая паранойя хороша в меру: если выделить достаточный буфер, то можно спокойно работать - так как здесь ситуация точно известная, зная, длиннее чего не окажется вывод `int`, проблемы с выходом за границы можно гарантированно избежать.